# MaterialDrawer MiniDrawer hamburger icon

Tags: materialdrawer

I use MiniDrawer implementation from [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) library.

I have tried to add ActionBarDrawerToggle to Drawer but got an Exception. MiniDrawer class does not allow to set ActionBarDrawerToggle

**Could you please tell is there way to set hamburger icon on toolbar for MiniDrawer ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ActionBarDrawerToggle` from Google requires you to use a `DrawerLayout` in the case of the normal `MiniDrawer` implementation of the `MaterialDrawer` there is no `DrawerLayout` in place, so the default behavior won't work.

As you still want the **hamburger**-icon to toggle the `Menu` state you have to either set the `NavigationIcon` on your own. Or you check out a library like the following:
https://github.com/balysv/material-menu

This will allow you to have the same animations (and more) as `NavigationIcon` and forward the open / close events to the `Crossfader` which is used to have the fading animation from `MiniDrawer` to normal `Drawer` size.

Comment: thanks for explanation and big thanks for MaterialDrawer amaising library!